# Fonts being precompiled but not accessible from helpers

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a custom font I made that is being compiled in my rails application:

```
I, [2015-09-01T13:38:57.301573 #10476]  INFO -- : Writing     /public/assets/icons-62920aea1811c9998d566b5b908a9199.eot
I, [2015-09-01T13:38:57.311575 #10476]  INFO -- : Writing     /public/assets/icons-baf7f6201807b5672ee6122cc0bc52dd.svg
I, [2015-09-01T13:38:57.323575 #10476]  INFO -- : Writing     /public/assets/icons-390fe92685fd76255a36d71c2977516b.ttf
I, [2015-09-01T13:38:57.332575 #10476]  INFO -- : Writing     /public/assets/icons-8695a8c5b193c6423e0b3b7a9c71b808.woff
I, [2015-09-01T13:38:57.339576 #10476]  INFO -- : Writing     /public/assets/ico-addcart-hover-86c1b956b7961e717fa3902779ae46a2.svg
```

These files are accessible if I manually add these hashed resources in my css file, but I cannot get the generated css to have that path:

Generated css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "icons";
  src: url(/assets/icons.eot);
  src: url(/assets/icons.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/assets/icons.woff) format("woff"), url(/assets/icons.ttf) format("truetype"), url(/assets/icons.svg#icons2) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "icons2";
    src: url(/assets/icons.svg#icons2) format("svg");
}
```

My code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "icons";
  src: font-url("icons.eot");
  src: font-url("icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       font-url("icons.woff") format("woff"),
       font-url("icons.ttf") format("truetype"),
       font-url("icons.svg#icons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "icons";
    src: font-url("icons.svg#icons") format("svg");
  }
}
```

How can I either:

- remove the precompilation for just those assets?
- Have my css actually work and generate the proper paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a better solution than this at the moment:

production.rb:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```